# IntelliSence in Visual Studio 2012: No members available for Inner classes in class template?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, inner-classes

I am wondering why in Visual Studio 2012 Desktop when I type:

```
    struct a
    {
        struct b
        {
            int foo;
        };

    b bar;
    bar.
    };
```

The IntelliSense calls:"No members available". Ie. when I type "bar." within struct a.
And my question is - Is this Visual Studio 2012 bug, or my stupidly? For me this is very annoying and I pray for anything to fix that.

Edit:
Although I acted dumb when I writed code like that, I still have this problem even in functions. But I figured out one big requirement - it must be class template.
So true code is:

```
    template<typename def>
    class lista
    {
    private:
     struct wezel
     {
             int poprz;
     };
     wezel* current;
    public:
     void do_tylu()
     {
         current->
     }
    };
```

And then IntelliSense start to crush...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example, you are typing an expression outside of a method (or field initializer). This is not allowed in C++, so the IntelliSense algorithm has no useful information to offer.

Try the following instead:

```
struct a
{
    struct b
    {
        int foo;
    };

    b bar;

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        bar.
    }
};
```

Comment: The question is actually about C++, but the answer is valid for that language as well :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say that I am writting in C++, my bad.

Comment: @user2241570: You did. The question is tagged as C++ ;)

Comment: I should have noticed the tags. I edited the post, but the answer is actually still the same.

Comment: Hm. Yeah, my bad again, it was really dumb... Also I figured out what my problem was, so I going to edit question